# Impact of capacitor on half-wave ac to dc rectifier

Tags: rectifier

I'm trying to convert 24AC from a furnace into a DC signal I can step down to power a 5 volt microprocessor. Following [this blog post](https://rayshobby.net/wordpress/24vac-to-5vdc-conversion/) I bought a [1n4002 diode](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/1n4002-tp/micro-commercial-components) and a [220 uF capacitor](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/25px220mefc6.3x11/rubycon). Then I built this circuit:

[image]

To test it I'm using a used power-supply that used to power security cameras. Using my multi-meter I see that the power-supply outputs 28 volts AC when I measure across the leads of my capacitor I get .06 volts DC.

Its kind of working, but I expected a lot more volts because according to the article the peak AC voltage should be even higher then the 28 volts. I'm wondering if using a 220 uF capacitor instead of a 100 uF capacitor would cause this difference? What math would I want to be doing to calculate if my capacitor is the wrong one?

Comment: Measure the capacitor voltage using the DC scales of the meter.

Comment: Is your DC Ground connected to one side of the AC source?

Comment: @Peter Bennett yes one of the AC source wires is what I'm using for my DC ground since that's connected to the negative pole of my capacitor.

Comment: If analogsystemsrf's answer doesn't help: Did you perhaps connect the capacitor backwards? I suspect you'd probably know by now if you did, though, since it's kind of hard not to notice an electrolytic capacitor venting...

Comment: Simon, you should be measuring 39.6 volts DC across that capacitor. As mentioned above, make sure your meter is set to read DC volts. Make sure your AC return is connected to 'GND'. Make sure capacitor is wired correctly. I hate it when they blow up.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I was confused at first by your question. After reading the other guys comments I think you were just checking that I set my multimeter to DC mode? If so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bought a 25VDC capacitor. There should be close to 40VDC across it, so it's probably leaking like crazy.

You need at least a 50V-rated capacitor for this. The peak voltage (ignoring the diode drop) is \$\sqrt{2}\approx 1.414\$ times the RMS voltage - what your meter purports to read- so about 40V for 28VAC sine wave in.

But many regulator circuits will either be marginal or into prohibited territory with that much input voltage. Linear regulators, even if they can handle 40V in, will likely get too hot- they're wasting more than eight times as much power as the load uses. Really, you'd most likely be better off to buy a wall-plug adapter that provides a regulated 5VDC.

Comment: Oh, I see that with the voltage rating rating now. Thanks for checking that. Thanks for the advice on not using a linear regulator do you think a switching regulator would do or would that still make a lot of waste? Does it make sense to wait a day or two till I buy the right capacitor to check your therory or accept your question now?

Comment: It's good to wait abut 24hrs or so before accepting to see if better answers show up. It's possible to comment later or un-accept if the answer is right or wrong later, at many people do that to close the loop.

Comment: A switching regulator will not have the same waste, however you need to get one rated for something like 50VDC in or more. The common LM2696 modules are not acceptable. A 12V transformer would be much better

Comment: The properly rated capacitor does work! As @Sparky256 predicted I'm getting around 39 volts DC. Other side question Spehro what did you mean by my old one was leaking? Did you mean physically like a batter?

Comment: Electrically, so it acted like it had a relatively low value resistor in parallel. You should discard it now, it's kaput.